# .Net - Dispose correctly children object

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dispose, code-analysis

From code analysis (Visual studio), I got this warning:

Warning 2   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : ... Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'l' before all references to it are out of scope...

So, I changed the code :

```
Dim l As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl
AddHandler l.DataBinding, AddressOf OnDataBinding
container.Controls.Add(l)
```

to

```
Dim l As LiteralControl = Nothing
Try
    l = New LiteralControl
    AddHandler l.DataBinding, AddressOf OnDataBinding
    container.Controls.Add(l)
Finally
    If Not l Is Nothing Then
        l.Dispose()
    End If
End Try
```

The warning disappear but then the literal control isn't anymore being displayed on the page...

### EDIT

Note that the code come from a Microsoft web page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.instantiatein.aspx

Comment: `1` is a horrible variable name.

Comment: It's only an example. I haven't put the real code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the warning is *really* about how the item could be created and then never actually hooked up to the container.  *hypothetically* (but not realisticly), the AddHandler call could fail, and then the control would never be added to the container, and then nobody would ever dispose it.

instead of disposing on the **finally** (which is destroying your object *all the time*) you need to change that to a **catch**, and dispose in the catch, then rethrow the exception.

That will get rid of the warning and give you correct handling of dispose.  Yes, in this specific case it isn't realistic, but it is possible.

Comment: Alternately, you could keep the `finally`, but null out the variable at the end of the `try`. Same difference, though, and your suggestion is probably clearer. I'm just offering this as something closer to the original.

Comment: @Steven: I think nulling out the variable at the end of the "try" is better than a catch-and-rethrow.  Catching and rethrowing an exception can sometimes jinx the stack trace; further, if an exception is thrown that won't be handled, a catch and rethrow will cause the apparent point of the error to be the rethrow, rather than the location where the exception originally occurred.

Comment: @supercat: Throwing a new exception would lose the stack trace, unless you use the original exception as the inner exception of the new one. As far as I know, rethrowing it with `throw;` will not harm the stack trace and will not make it look like the exception originated in the catch block.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Catch and rethrow, even using an unadorned "throw", will slightly jinx the stack trace, at least as of vs2010.  If method "CatchAndThrow" calls "Foo" from line 23, and Foo throws an exception which is caught and then rethrown at line 57, the stack trace will include information about what happened within "Foo", but will indicate that the exception came through line 57 of CatchAndThrow, rather than line 23.

Comment: @supercat: You are correct, but it only shows the line number if the PDB is available; otherwise it shows just the method. Since I only care about the stack trace when the code runs in production, and I don't normally ship a PDB, this is a non-issue for me.